# multiple spark jobs run concurrently

Tags: apache-spark

i have spark run in localhost, and i want to read data from three topics kafka using job spark, i  executed this job from script shell using also command line parameter

```
/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit --class "org.apache.sparkwordcount.SparkCassandra" --master spark://ubuntu:7077 '/home/darif/TestProject/wordcounts/target/wordcounts-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'  test1 &

/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit --class "org.apache.sparkwordcount.SparkCassandra" --master spark://ubuntu:7077 '/home/darif/TestProject/wordcounts/target/wordcounts-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'  test2 &

/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit --class "org.apache.sparkwordcount.SparkCassandra" --master spark://ubuntu:7077 '/home/darif/TestProject/wordcounts/target/wordcounts-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'  test3 &
```

but only one of this works, and two athers already in state "WAINTING"

can you tell what is the problem here please? Thansk

Comment: Some reading for you: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html

Comment: all of the three jobs are executed with same SparkContext, this is the problem, no ?

Comment: What happens when the 1st job finishes? I assume you are pointing all the jobs to the same cluster, so they will wait for the completion of the previous job before executing.

Comment: yes exactly, when i stoped the 1st job, the two rest jobs are already in state "WAITINING" and when i stoped one of them, the rest one is go to "RUNING"